# replace all backslashes when they are escaped multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I made a mistake in a app I'm developing and it turns out that there are some text that have multiples times double quotes escaped, something like this

> We will begin by constructing the front and sides of the bar.   We
>   will first create frames for both the front and sides using
>   2\\\\\\\\" x 4\\\\\\\\"s and will then secure particle
>   board panels over the frames. The bar in this project is
>   42\\\\\\\\" tall by 60\\\\\\\\" wide by
>   40\\\\\\\\" deep.   You will be drilling several screws in this
>   project.  To make this process easier- first drill pilot holes for the
>   screws in your frame using your Dremel Rotary Tool and a 150
>   1/8\\\\\\\\" Drill Bit.

I'm looking for a way to do an update in the DB that remove all those slashes quickly, so far my thinking is to use a regular expression, something like

```
for each($records as $record){
  $record->description = preg_replace(*/some patter here/*, $record->description);
  $record->save();
}
```

However I'm having a hard time looking for the correct pattern, so maybe someone can please help with this, or if there is a easier or better way to updates these records, I really appreciate any help!

Comment: `update yourfield set field=replace(yourfield, '\\\\', '\\') where yourfield like '\\\\'`, basically. just do a repeated string update until no records are matched.

Comment: If the number of backslashes is the same in every case, you can just write a pattern to change that into \".  If they're different, replace \\" with \" multiple times.  The pattern would be /\\\\"/.  That's two escaped backslashes and a quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost never be storing backslash-escaped content in the database. To clean these up you probably want something like:

```
preg_replace( "/\\\\{2,}/", "", $record->description );
```

That will replace sequences of 2 or more backslashes with the empty string. If necessary you can make it more specific -- so that it would only match those sequences of backslashes followed by a double-quote character:

```
preg_replace( '/\\\\{2,}"/', '"', $record->description );
```

That's if you want to do it via PHP. Your database engine may have a built-in regular expression replace function that would allow you to perform the update just using a query, and would likely be higher performance, if that matters. The pattern would likely be the same.

I just noticed your MySQL tag. Apparently MySQL does not have a built-in regex replace function. See [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

My suggestion is to get rid of the backslash escapes completely and then escape as necessary on output, unless there's a good reason to store the content escaped. You could of course alter the replacement string to replace those sequences with a single backslash or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("/([\\]){2,}/", "\\", $record->description);
```

should do the trick.